# Does Dimension Door preserve momentum?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Looking at https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door and thinking of its use as a parachute.

If falling at terminal velocity, and Dimension Door is cast, would the caster (and anything or anyone with them) appear travelling at speed?

Comment: @NeilsSchoenfelder Please don't answer in comments. Even (especially?) on closed questions. If you think that answer is worthwhile, please post it as a full one on the dupe target. It is the place where this should be answered.